# Add or embed video in pdf

Tags: pdf, dompdf

I am currently using dompdf in generating pdf files.
I am stuck with adding or embedding videos in the pdf.
Unfortunately, I can't find any reference on this.

I am hoping that anyone can confirm if it is possible.
I will also appreciate it if you can provide me a sample for this.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can embed movies and Flash SWF files into PDFs using Acrobat's ISO-32000-1 extensions. See page 76 of http://www.adobe.ca/content/dam/Adob...t_iso32000.pdf

You should be able to achieve this with a little experimentation of your PDF library lets you add custom objects to the object stream, and depending on how good your PDF writing library is you might end up doing a lot of the hard work.

A good example would be iText which supports it through `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.richmedia.*`

However, just because it's possible doesn't mean it's justified, nor will it work in anything but Acrobat and totally excludes iPads and other tablets/devices.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of dompdf is that it does not support embedding videos in PDF but it is also unlikely that even if it did, it is unlikely that your HTML would contain the correct attributes to create them. In HTML, most people link to video that is hosted somewhere other than their own site. These sites don't generally allow links directly to the video file itself but rather to a parameterized URL. Acrobat and the other viewers that support rich media don't recognize those URLs as being playable. The URL must be directly to the video file itself or it needs to be downloaded and embedded by dompdf... but again... these sites don't allow for that. Additionally, you'd need to create a video player in Flash and embed that into the PDF as well, I don't see anything in dompdf that allows you to specify a .swf to be used as the player.

Answer (score 0):

DomPDF did not support Embedded video
But you can do the following solution

- create an image tag with a video thumbnail
- Link image tag to the video URL via  tag

So the solution will look like.

```
<a href="https://video-url" target="_blank" ><img src="https://image-url" /></a>
```